# Return value from nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get values from a nested dict via user input. The problem is that the nested dictionaries have generic names (d1,d1, etc.). The user inputs, say, last name and the program returns the email.

I know this is basic, so I apologize in advance. This is what I have so far.

```
my_dict = {
    'd1':{
        'fname':'john',
        'lname':'doe',
        'age':'26',
        'email':'jdoe@mail.com'
    },
    'd2':{
        'fname':'mary',
        'lname':'jane',
        'age':'32',
        'email':'mjane@mail.com'
    }
}

lname = input("enter last name: ")

for emp in my_dict.items():
    print(emp)
```

Output:

```
enter last name: john
('d1', {'fname': 'john', 'lname': 'doe', 'age': '26', 'email': 'jdoe@mail.com'})
('d2', {'fname': 'mary', 'lname': 'jane', 'age': '32', 'email': 'mjane@mail.com'})
```

Comment: You could iterate through `my_dict` until you find the person you're looking for with [.items()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).

Comment: Tried that, but it won't make much difference. It returns each nested dict,, but it won't return the value needed.

Comment: Why are the dicts stored in a dict? Why not a list?

Comment: @Bharel I was just trying to make sense of nested dicts. Why would you prefer to use a list of dicts? Is there any advantage?

Comment: Of course, using a placeholder as a dict name instead of using a list of dictionaries is boh slower and takes more memory. It is also less readable, as someone is trying to understand why use a dict in here in the first place.

Comment: @Bharel Could you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function that takes a last name as input, then iterates over each dictionary (key, value) pair and returns the email as soon as there is a match:

```
def get_email_from_last_name(last_name):
    for v in my_dict.values():
        if v['lname'] == last_name:
            return v['email']

lname = input("enter last name: ")
email = get_email_from_last_name(lname)
print(email)
```

prints:

```
enter last name: doe
jdoe@mail.com
```

Comment: If you don’t need `k` at all, you could simply iterate through `.values()` instead of `.items()`…

Comment: good point, just adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per OP's comment, here is a solution with a simple tuple instead:

```
my_data = (
    {
        'fname':'john',
        'lname':'doe',
        'age':'26',
        'email':'jdoe@mail.com'
    },
    {
        'fname':'mary',
        'lname':'jane',
        'age':'32',
        'email':'mjane@mail.com'
    }
)

lname = input("enter last name: ")
for person in my_data:
  if lname == person["lname"]:
    print(person)
```

You can also map according to the last name, but that is not necessarily a one-to-one relationship.